# Assigning values to attributes in the BUILD phaser for an object

Tags: oop, raku

When a `BUILD` phaser is called, it overrides default attribute assignment in Perl6. Suppose we have to use that BUILD phaser, like we do in [this module](https://github.com/fayland/perl6-WebService-GitHub/blob/master/lib/WebService/GitHub/Role.pm) (that's where I met this problem). What's the way of assigning values to attributes in that phase?
I have used this

```
class my-class {
    has $.dash-attribute;

    submethod BUILD(*%args) {
        for %args.kv -> $k, $value {
            self."$k"( $value );
        }
    }
};

my $my-instance = my-class.new( dash-attribute => 'This is the attribute' );
```

And I get this error

```
Too many positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 2
```

Other combinations of `$!`or `$.`, direct assignment, declaring the attribute as `rw` (same error) yield different kind of errors. This is probably just a syntax issue, but I couldn't find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to write it like that, if the absence of the `BUILD` method would already give you the same functionality.  Assuming you want to add some logic later, maybe a `TWEAK` method would be better in that situation?  Please see https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Object_Construction

Comment: It's the basic code to reproduce the error; in fact, it uses the BUILD phase to add roles. Which probably can be done elsewhere, too.

Comment: Ditto what @ElizabethMattijsen said above. If the only thing you want is to assign to attributes, you don't need the BUILD phase at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your example, the way I see it.  First of all, if you want an attribute to be writeable, you will need to mark it `is rw`.  Secondly, changing the value of an attribute is done by assignment, rather than by giving the new value as an argument.

So I think the code should be:

```
class my-class {
    has $.dash-attribute is rw;

    submethod BUILD(*%args) {
        for %args.kv -> $k, $value {
            self."$k"() = $value;
        }
    }
};

my $my-instance = my-class.new( dash-attribute => 'attribute value' );
dd $my-instance;
# my-class $my-instance = my-class.new(dash-attribute => "attribute value")
```

Comment: What is the parenthesis after `"$k"` for?

Comment: That's the Perl 6 syntax to indicate that you want to call a method of which the name is in the variable `$k`.  Compare: `say Int.new; # 0` with `say Int."new" # Quoted method name requires parenthesized arguments. If you meant to concatenate two strings, use '~'.` with `say Int."new"()   # 0

Comment: Thanks! It caught me off guard when I saw parentheses and assignment together like that.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it the same way the object system normally does it under the hood for you.
(not recommended)

```perl6
class C {
  has $.d;

  submethod BUILD ( *%args ){
    for self.^attributes {
      my $short-name = .name.substr(2); # remove leading ｢$!｣
      next unless %args{$short-name}:exists;
      .set_value( self, %args{$short-name} )
    }
  }
}

say C.new(d => 42)
```

```
C.new(d => 42)
```

Comment: I hadn't realized it, but `set_value` is actually documented and tested in roast.  More information: https://docs.perl6.org/routine/set_value